# How to delete files from android old sdk folder under Windows 10

Tags: android, command, window

I install android sdk into **android-sdk** folder and then android studio with android-sdk into path **sdk** by installer. 
I used just the path sdk from android studio.
I try to delete the old **android-sdk** but I got this error:

```
...\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\AdbWinUsbApi.dll
Access is denied.
```

I used also this to try to get access:

```
takeown /f android-sdk /r /d y 
icacls android-sdk /grant administrators:F /t
```

also with my username account.

How to remove the folder with all content?

Comment: Close android studio, open the windows taskmanager and kill adb.exe.

Comment: I don't used adb.exe or any software when I try to delete the folder, also the adb process not running when I try to perform this task.The antivirus don't block anything... Maybe some security/share settings of files versus trust application. But I'm not sure.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is fixed new Android Studio version 2.2.3 new instalation.